# Issue with bundle exec rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error while running the bundle exec rake db:migrate command

```
D:\Sravan\RaiilsProject>bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem binaries with `bundle install`
```

I have already ran bundle install command and also my gem file contains the following entry
gem "rake","=0.8.7"

Could you please help us on this?

---

Actually I am using rails 2.3.5 version. So I am using rake 0.8.7 version
while running rake db:migrate the rake task is working fine but getting the following error

D:\Idea\8263_branch>rake db:migrate
(in D:/Sravan/RailsProject)
Cannot find or read D:/Sravan/RailsProject/config/newrelic.yml
rake aborted!
You have already activated i18n 0.6.4, but your Gemfile requires i18n 0.4.2. Consider using bundle exec.
D:/Sravan/RailsProject/Rakefile:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'

I have also tried by replacing gem "rake","=0.8.7" with gem "rake","~> 0.8.7"
But still getting the same error

Comment: The path `D:\Sravan\RaiilsProject` looks like it's on windows :)

Comment: Yes. my project is on windows.

Answer (score 1):

have you done `gem install rake` on your command line or edited the gemfile manually?  In either case, `"rake","=0.8.7"` doesn't look right to me...shouldn't it be written as:

`gem "rake","~> 0.8.7"`

Comment: Actually I am using rails 2.3.5 version. So I am using rake 0.8.7 version
while running rake db:migrate the rake task is working fine but getting the following error

D:\Idea\8263_branch>rake db:migrate
(in D:/Sravan/RailsProject)
Cannot find or read D:/Sravan/RailsProject/config/newrelic.yml
rake aborted!
You have already activated i18n 0.6.4, but your Gemfile requires i18n 0.4.2. Consider using bundle exec.
D:/Sravan/RailsProject/Rakefile:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'

I have also tried by replacing gem "rake","=0.8.7" with gem "rake","~> 0.8.7"
But still getting the same error

Comment: try running this on the command line: `gem install -v=0.4.2 i18n`